# ¿Por qué NERDTree se abre siempre a la derecha?

Tags: vim

Siempre que inicio el comando `:NERDTree` en mi editor *Vim* se abre en el buffer de la derecha. Llevo varios días leyendo la documentación al respecto y no consigo que se abra en la izquierda, en teoría se debería de abrir por defecto en la izquierda.

Mi archivo  **NERD_Tree.vim** se ve así:

```
call s:initVariable("g:NERDTreeWinPos", "left")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo .vimrc tiene includa la instrucción let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "left", linea 59:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por tu respuesta, no me dio la solución pero si la idea para encontrala.

En mi archivo .vimrc tengo la siguiente línea:

```
source ~/vim_rumtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
```

Pues bien dentro de plugings_config.vim tenía la siguiente línea:

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
```

He comentado esa línea y problema solucionado. De nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Añade esto a tu **.vimrc**, para forzarlo a abrirse en el lado izquierdo (Sin el call).

```
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "left"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, olvidé mencionar en el la pregunta que mi archivo .vimrc tiene includa la linea que tu propones. Vuelvo a editar mi pregunta para mostralo. Esta en la línea 59. Una vez más gracias..

Comment: Puede ser que de alguna manera tu archivo **NERD_Tree.vim** pise la configuracion del .vimrc? Si lo eliminamos y usamos solo .vimrc? Me deja bastante perplejo este error. Si me ha ocurrido que al cerrar una tab se posicione solo a la derecha, pero nunca al abrirlo, al tener dicha configuracion puesta.